# Reactor Mono zip+map vs flatMap/Map

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

when calling three different services and waiting for the response in parallel, such as this:

```
Mono<A> mono1 = service1.call().scheduleOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Mono<B> mono2 = service2.call().scheduleOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Mono<C> mono3 = service3.call().scheduleOn(Schedulers.parallel());
```

i can now do this to wait for all results:

```
Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3).map(t -> {
  A res1 = t.getT1();
  B res2 = t.getT2();
  C res3 = t.getT3(); 
  ...
})
```

or i can do this:

```
mono1.flatMap(res1 -> mono2.flatMap( res2 -> mono3.map( res3 -> {
  ...
}
```

for Flux, this is a difference, i think, but whats the difference in THIS scenario (except being a bit more convoluted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there shouldn't be any difference performance-wise. you can use something like this to simulate some delay:

```
private Mono<String> waitAndReturn(long wait, String response) {
    return Mono.fromFuture(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(wait);
            return response;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }));
}
```

and then play with it locally:

```
@Test
@SneakyThrows
void test3() {
    Mono<String> mono1 = waitAndReturn(1000L, "foo");
    Mono<String> mono2 = waitAndReturn(2000L, "bar");
    Mono<String> mono3 = waitAndReturn(3000L, "buzz");

    log.info("Mono.zip starts here");
    Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3)
            .map(t -> t.getT1() + t.getT2() + t.getT3())
            .subscribe(r -> log.info("Mono.zip ends here. " + r));

    log.info("Mono.flatMap starts here");
    mono1.flatMap(
        res1 -> mono2.flatMap(
            res2 -> mono3.map(
                res3 -> res1 + res2 + res3
            )
        )
    ).subscribe(r -> log.info("Mono.flatMap ends here. " + r));


    Thread.sleep(10000l);
}
```